# How to solve complex equations in python?

Tags: python, sympy, complex-numbers

I want to solve the equation in python:

```
x+conj(x)=2
x-conj(x)=4
```

Then, ovbiously x is 1+2i.

In python, I am using sympy and lumpy package like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFWCD.png).

BUT! there is no outcome. just blanket came up.
What should I do to solve these equations in python?

Comment: Instead of posting an image of your code, can you please post the actual code in text. It will help everyone to review and provide feedback.

Answer (score 2):

You really can't mix numpy and sympy expressions.  Numpy doesn't understand sympy's functions nor symbols, and vice versa sympy doesn't understand about unevaluated numpy functions.

Therefore, you need to write everything with sympy functions.

Note that your system of equations doesn't have a solution. For example in the second equation (`x-conj(x)`) gives `4i` for `x=1+2i`.

Unfortunately, sympy doesn't work very well with this type of equations. A straightforward way to write them, would be:

```py
from sympy import symbols, Eq, conjugate, solve, I, re, im

x = symbols('x')
solve([Eq(x + conjugate(x), 2), Eq(x - conjugate(x), 4*I)])
```

which wrongly gives no solution.

Some experimenting does give a way to write the equations and get the expected outcome:

```py
xc = re(x) - I * im(x)
solve([Eq(x + xc, 2), Eq(x - xc, 4 * I)])
```

Output: `[{x: 1 + 2*I, re(x): 1, im(x): 2}]`